# How to delete a node in Ternary Tree?

Tags: algorithm, ternary-tree

I am working on implementing a Java program on inserting and deleting a node in a *ternary tree*.

I am able to implement *insertion* without any issues, but I'm facing a few hiccups in implementing the *deletion* operation.

So, my question is:

> How to delete a node from ternary tree if it has one or more child nodes?

It will be great if you can share any *logic* or *pseudo-code* to implement the "delete" functionality.

Comment: Have you looked at how B-trees do it? Also, you typically don't want to delete nodes, you want to delete *values*, and those don't have children

Comment: Try doing it on a piece of paper first. Start with the simplest case you can think of and try to specify what you want the tree to look like after deletion – “ternary tree” by itself says nothing about which node goes where or which shape the tree has, unless you use the term differently than what I learned ages ago.

Comment: Can you specify **few hiccups**?

Comment: The hiccup I am facing is how to delete a node if it has more than one child node. Let me try what @niklas_b told, try moving the data and not deleting the node.

Comment: For a start, read through the code for deletio in a binary search tree. Understand why it is done that way, and design similar code for yor ternary tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

---

Suppose `n` is the node we want to delete, `l` is its left child, `r` is its right child and `m` is its middle child.

- If `n` is a *root* node, then make `n` `null`.
- If `n` is **not** a root node, then check if `m` is **not `null`**. If so, simply invoke recursively the current procedure on `m`, since `m` matches `n` in value: we will delete the last matching node!
- If `m` is **`null`**, then we have the following possible cases:

  - If both `l` and `r` are `null`, then make `l`, `r` and `m` values in the parent node `n` to be `null`.
  - If **only one** node, say `x`, (either `l` or `r`) is **not** `null`, then replace `x` non-null value with `n`'s value, and delete `x`.
  - If both `l` **and** `r` are **not** `null`, then find the node `z` with **maximum** value in the **left sub-tree** of `n`, and replace `z`'s value to with `n`'s node,  and delete `z`.